# Verify if Cookie exists and storing the information

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, storage, verify

I'm new to Javascript/Ajax and I'm trying to store a user's name using cookies. I have a form and would like to remember the person's first name (id = firstName). If they already filled it out in the past I want to display his/her name in a span element the next time they visit the page.

This is what I would like to do using pseudo code. I hope it's clear....

If cookie (called name) exists, display that information in the tag element "span"

else

Store that cookie when  the user fills out the form

(I have an input with type="submit" as my button if that matters)

---

@banana right now I modified my code to match all the tag names and ids i have. However nothing displays in the span if I type in a name in the form, submit and come back after on the page.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, milliseconds) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (milliseconds));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

document.onload = checkIfCookieExists;
function checkIfCookieExists(){
var firstNameFromCookie = getCookie('firstName');
if(firstNameFromCookie == ''){
   // cookie wasnt set

}
else{
   // cookie was set
   var display = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
   display.innerHTML = firstNameFromCookie;
}
}

function init(){
 var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
 var cookieExpieryTimeInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60; //1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minutes - results in 1 hour time.
 setCookie('firstName',firstName ,cookieExpieryTimeInMilliseconds );
}

window.onload = init();
```

Comment: you can use `localStorage` also.

Comment: I need the code to be server side unfortunately. If I'm not mistaken localstorage is more client side.

Comment: Cookies in clientside Javascript are only clientside.

Comment: If need is server side then the cookie is better.

Comment: @fzzle, server side language(eg:- php) can read the value set by javascript cookie.

Comment: @ fzzle wrong, cookies can be serverside too. @ Joseph Montecalvo javascript is not serverside however, if u want it to be serverside please specify what language you use (php/asp/jsp/whatever)

Comment: @Banana and -SumanBogati Javascript is tagged.

Comment: @fzzle your previous comment "cookies are only clientside" had no javascript reference in it, thats what i answered on. but you are correct now, javascript is clientside only therefore handling cookies with javascript would be on client's machine only

Comment: @Banana I'm using Ajax

Comment: @Banana When the question is about Javascript I assume that's what we're discussing.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I'm using Javascript and Ajax

Comment: @JosephMontecalvo Javascript was tagged - it should be clear.

Answer (score -1):

use those to handle cookies. simply getCookie with the name you want and see if u get an empty value.

client side:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, milliseconds) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (milliseconds));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

EDIT:

```
document.onload = checkIfCookieExists;
function checkIfCookieExists(){
    var firstNameFromCookie = getCookie('first_name');
    if(firstNameFromCookie == ''){
       // cookie wasnt set

    }
    else{
       // cookie was set
       var yourSpan = document.getElementById('yourSpansID');
       yourSpan.innerHTML = firstNameFromCookie;
    }
}
```

in order to save a cookie using the functions above, you simply do this:

```
function whatever_Function_You_Use_To_Submit_Users_Details(){
     var firstName = ... whatever you do to retrieve first name after user inserted in
     var cookieExpieryTimeInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60; //1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minutes - results in 1 hour time.
     setCookie('first_name',firstName ,cookieExpieryTimeInMilliseconds );
}
```

Comment: I've done a lot of research in the past couple of days with cookies and my question has always been when looking at examples, where do you call the id="firstName". How do I display whatever the user types into the input id "firstName" in my span element.

Comment: you should call it in document.onload, when the page loads you check if a cookie exists, if yes you simply paste the value you received into your span, if not then you dont. ill update my answer in a sec;

Comment: Ok, I'll try and implement this into my code and see what happens. The only problems I have is really grasping the concept. I'll get back to you soon

Comment: sure. if you need further assistance regarding the code please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

To read cookies, you can use **Zeus.js**'s built-in `zeus.getCookie()` function.

`zeus.getCookie()` works like this:

- All Cookies are smooshed into a single string, `document.cookie`
- `zeus.getCookie()` picks out the desired key from the string
- A string is returned.

For example, if you set a cookie, `document.cookie = "like=trains"`, you can use `zeus.getCookie("like")` to return the value, `trains` (as a string).

To use **Zeus.js**, simply put

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/thetakeaway/zeus.js/master/zeus.js"></script>
```

in `<head></head>`.

Cheers!